# How can I solve "Cannot find module" using Yarn?

Tags: node.js, next.js, yarnpkg

I'm trying to deploy a nextjs project that I've updated to version 13.when I deploy the following error occurs:

```
> Build error occurred
Error: Cannot find module 'picocolors'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio-react\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\css-syntax- 
error.js
- C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio-react\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\postcss.js
- C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio-react\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\font- 
stylesheet-gathering-plugin.js    
- C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio-react\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-config.js
- C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio-react\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js
- C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio-react\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-build.js
- C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio-react\node_modules\next\dist\lib\commands.js
- C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio-react\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at mod._resolveFilename (C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio- 
    react\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:23:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Arotiana's\portfolio- 
    react\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\css-syntax-error.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    "C:\\Users\\Arotiana's\\portfolio- 
     react\\node_modules\\next\\node_modules\\postcss\\lib\\css-syntax-error.js",        
    "C:\\Users\\Arotiana's\\portfolio- 
    react\\node_modules\\next\\node_modules\\postcss\\lib\\postcss.js",
    "C:\\Users\\Arotiana's\\portfolio- 
    react\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\build\\webpack\\plugins\\font-stylesheet-gathering- 
    plugin.js",
    "C:\\Users\\Arotiana's\\portfolio-react\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\build\\webpack- 
    config.js",
    "C:\\Users\\Arotiana's\\portfolio-react\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\build\\index.js",
    "C:\\Users\\Arotiana's\\portfolio-react\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\cli\\next-build.js",
    "C:\\Users\\Arotiana's\\portfolio-react\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\lib\\commands.js",
    "C:\\Users\\Arotiana's\\portfolio-react\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\bin\\next"
  ]
}
```

I've already try tried to install picocolors but when I deploy this error alwais comes. How can I solve it?

Comment: Could it be related to `'` in the user name?

Comment: @Anatoly I've moved the project into another directory but the message still persist

Comment: Can you show your package.json in the post?

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly, I have already solved It  a week ago by changing the version of modules in package.json